How do I complete the preprocessing of NGSIM dataset?
In the proposed work, it is required to preprocess the NGSIM dataset for vehicle trajectory prediction. Currently, I have visualized the dataset using
'''
import pandas as pd
data = read_csv'URL'
data
'''
Equally, I have been able to extract the data for US-101 through filtering in excel.
Question:
How do I:

Filter Vehicles on Lanes 1-5:

Consider only the vehicles present on lanes 1 to 5.


Identify Target Vehicles on Lanes 2-4:

Find the target vehicles that are present on lanes 2 to 4.


Extract Trajectory Data:

Extract the trajectory data along with the frame number, vehicle ID, lane number, time, and position for the target vehicles.


Frame-by-Frame Analysis for Each Target Vehicle:

For each target vehicle, process the data frame by frame.

4.1 Identify Vehicles in Each Frame:
- For each frame, identify the target vehicle and the surrounding vehicle IDs.
4.2 Determine Positions:
- Find the positions of the identified vehicles.

Save Variables:

Save all variables for the target vehicle.


Repeat for Next Target Vehicle:

Repeat steps 3 to 5 for the next target vehicle.



problem based on the observed historical trajectory. The dataset to be used for evaluating different vehicle trajectory prediction models is that of "the Next Generation Simulation (NGSIM)" data, collected by the U.S. Department of Transportation. This dataset consists of 11.8 million items of data with 25 attributes (columns), such as the  vehicle’s coordinates and velocity. The sampling frequency of data is 10 Hz.
However, I had gotten the dataset (NGSIM) and prepared the mathematical model as that in this link https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9832594
Since am using Python, Pytorch, and Anaconda IDE, what libraries do I need t  launch first?
